# Django request.GET. Search. Different results, depending on the value

Tags: django

There is a search form. It has a drop-down list. Each item in this list has different meanings. After clicking, a search is performed, ulr looks as follows:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?wantbuy=kv
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?wantbuy=ls
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?wantbuy=km
```

**my views.py:**

```
kv = kv.objects.all()
ls = ls.objects.all()
km = km.objects.all()

if 'wantbuy' in request.GET:
    wantbuy = request.GET['wantbuy']
    if wantbuy:
        queryset_list = km
```

Now, it doesn’t matter what value it 'wantbuy', I get all the objects from 'km'.
Tell me how to do it better? As for each url value, display your objects? I want to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?wantbuy=kv
```

Shows all objects

```
kv = kv.objects.all()
```

etc.

Thank!

Comment: You need show more of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have several conditions to set the variable depending on the parameter

```
wantbuy = request.GET.get('wantbuy')
if wantbuy == 'kv':
    queryset_list = kv.object.all()
elif wantbuy == 'ls':
    queryset_list = ls.object.all()
elif wantbuy == 'km':
    queryset_list = km.object.all()
else:
    # Raise a 404 or do something else
```

Comment: What is the goal of this view though? A generic search for the entire site?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. Yes, this is a general search. And it works great! Thank!